# Parse Location of other User (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geolocation

im trying to build an app with parse where i can see location of other user - I know username of my friend and i want to get his last saved location (GeoPoint). This documentation didnt help me: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

[image]

Could u give me example code how can I get GeoPoint of this user from parse when i know his username?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the Geopoint is stored in your friend's User record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd ideally perform a query for the users, then if the user's username is equal to the string you want you can grab their location value via the location key.

Something like this... but play around with it.

```
let query = PFUser.query()

query.whereKey("Username", equalTo:"TheUsernameYouWantToGetLocationOf")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

     if error != nil {
      //print error
     }

    for object in objects  {

       if let geoPoint = object["GeoPoint"] as? PFGeoPoint {

       //then convert to cllocation here...

      }
    }


})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Echizzle!